# Transforming co-ordinates from a rectangle to a parallelogram

Tags: c#, geometry, coordinates

I am stuck on a simple yet vexing problem with basic geometry. Too bad I don;t remember my high-school co-ordinate geometry and looking for some help.

My problem is illustrated in this diagram: [A rectangle rotated, scaled, and warped into a parallelogram http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/8011/transform.png](http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/8011/transform.png)

I am struggling with transforming a co-ordinate from the rectangle to a resized parallelogram. Any tips, pointers and/or code-examples would be wonderful!

Thanks,
M.

Comment: What is the meaning of the angle 0 in the picture? If the result is both skewed and rotated, then I would think 2 angles are required to specify the transform.

Comment: I embedded the image for you.  I agree that 2 angles seem to be necessary to describe the transformation -- the angle of the corner of the parallelogram, and the angle by which the figure was rotated.

Comment: Angle theta is the angle between the 2 edges of the ||gm. BTW I might very well have missed a few variables, so pls. feel free to fill in the missing if any.

Comment: @Mikos : are you creating a custom form, or usercontrol, in your code in which case you must, indeed, calculate the transformation of points to build the path of the Form or control ? Or are you doing something in a 'Paint event using GDI+ : if the latter is the case, look into the Matrix class in GDI+, and its built-in affine transformation methods, like 'Shear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several steps in this transformation.

1. Scale about (x,y) to adjust to the final size W', H'. (Possibly unequal
   scaling on X and Y axes).
2. Apply a shear transform to convert
   the rectangle to a parallelogram
   (keeping x,y invariant).
3. Rotate about (x,y) to align to the
   final coordinate orientation.
4. Translate to the new location.

Create the coordinate matrices for each of these and composite (multiply) them together to create the overall transform. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) could be your starting point to know about these transformation matrices.

Tip: Might be simplest to apply a translation to move (x,y) to the origin first. Then, the shear, scaling and rotation are a lot simpler to do. Then move it to the new location.

Comment: Thanks I will look into your tips and the Wikipedia article. Appreciated.